# NullPointer when trying to move oval in java?

Tags: java, function, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

Im having an issue related to the paintComponent method in Java. Basically, what Im trying to do is move an oval across the screen using buttons.

```
//public class piedra
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //super.paintComponent(g);

    System.out.println(contador);

     if(contador >= 1) {

        g.fillOval(x, y, largo, ancho);

    }

    if (contador == 0) {

        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillOval(x, y, largo, ancho);
        contador++;

    }

}
```

Every variable is an attribute so I can manipulate them with the frame with buttons class.
This is what Im trying to do:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            piedra.y = piedra.y - 1;
            piedra.paintComponent(piedra.g);

        }
```

Im trying to move the oval across the screen using the paintComponent method, but when I press the button, the program throws a NullPointer Exception. I have already checked the Y variable and it changes after I press the button. That's it, Im pretty lost from this point on. I barely remember that there is a function that updates the screen, but I don't think it will do something about that Exception, right? Any possible solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are not suppose to call `paintComponent(piedra.g)` directly, you should instead call `repaint()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now it doesn´t throw any exception, but unfortunately it still doesn´t work, the oval just won´t move...

Comment: Confirm that piedra.y is the expected value inside paintComponent when that method is called. What happens when you press the button multiple times? Does piedra.y change every time?